# Android listview by adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I'm using adapter to add elements to listview. It's okay when I adding element by element. But  I need to element (parent) add one more element (child) witch belongs to parent. And I don't really know how to do that.
I think I need to create another item layout and append, but don't know how. Maybe some one have any ideas?

Comment: if I get your mean right you need Expandable listView

Comment: yea, make a new layout, and in the class that make your row, you can create a boolean atribute that can be false when you are making child

Answer (score 0):

Try using ViewHolder to define multiple elements which belong to the list item. Then append the ViewHolder to the adapter.

Create an inner class for ViewHolder

```
static class ViewHolder {
public TextView text;
public ImageView image;
```

}

Inside the getView, load the viewholder.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
      // configure view holder
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
      viewHolder.image = (ImageView) rowView
          .findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    // fill data
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();


    return rowView;
  }
```

Hope it's useful to you.